# Oracle database table in gridview

Tags: c#, winforms, oracle, gridview

I want to get the result from a query in my oracle database and put it in a gridview. Now my problem is, I have no idea how to output it in the gridview. I am using the gridview from the toolbox and my oracle connection is working. I also have the right `SELECT` query and I can output that in a listbox. I just have no idea how to do this in a gridview. I looked for it and I came across this: [How to populate gridview with mysql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16115985/how-to-populate-gridview-with-mysql) Although this doesn't help me.

How can I output it in a gridview so that it looks exactly the same as a normal table in the oracle database?

What should I use and how?

This is my code:

```
public void read()
        {
            try
            {
                var conn = new OracleConnection("")
                conn.Open();
                OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("select * from t1", conn);
                OracleDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                var column1 = reader["vermogen"];
                column = (column1.ToString());
                listBox1.Items.Add(column);
            }
            conn.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

    }
```

Comment: In which way the linked question has not helped? Are you talking about ASP.NET GridView or WinForms DataGridView?

Comment: @Steve Winforms. Well the answer is using mysql and has absolutely no explanation.

Comment: You just initialize a dataadapter & load the results inside a datatable. Then set the gridview's Data Source to that DataTable. Just as the link points out. It should work with any database.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To bind a `DataTable` to a `DataGridView` your code need simply to be changed to

```
    public void read()
    {
        try
        {
            using(OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection("....."))
            using(OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("select * from t1", conn))
            {
                conn.Open();
                using(OracleDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                     DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
                     dataTable.Load(reader);
                     dataGridView1.DataSource = dataTable;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
 }
```

The OracleDataReader could be passed to the Load method of the DataTable and then the table is ready to be bound to the DataGridView DataSource property. I have also added some using statement to ensure proper disposing of the disposable objects employed. (In particular the OracleConnection is very expensive to not close in case of exceptions)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DataSet` too:

```
   public void read()
   {
       try
       {
           OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection("");
           OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("select * from t1", conn);
           conn.Open();
           cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
           DataSet ds = new DataSet();
           OracleDataAdapter da = new OracleDataAdapter();
           da.SelectCommand = cmd;
           da.Fill(ds);
           dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];

       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
           MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
       }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First establish connection in case, you didnt establish globally by using connection string. Then use oleDbcommand for the oracle sql command you want to execute. In my case, it is 'select * from table_name' which would show all data from table to datagrid. I wrote this code in a button to display data on data grid.

```
{         
     OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection("");
     OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("select * from table_name", conn);

        {
            conn.Open();
            OleDbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            {
                DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
                dataTable.Load(reader);
                dataGridView1.DataSource = dataTable;
            }
            conn.Close();
        }
}
```

Comment: Consider adding an explanation about how and why this is the answer.  A code snippet alone does not help the OP.