# How to show data in a datagridview in oracle using c#

Tags: c#, oracle

I am trying to to execute stored procedure that I have created in my oracle and trying to show data from stored procedure into datagridview using C#.Someone please help me how do i execute stored procedure.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Oracle database table in gridview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21253463/oracle-database-table-in-gridview)

Answer (score 1):

It is actually pretty simple. You just call the stored procedure, use a `DataAdapter` and load/populate a `DataTable` from the adapter and finally bind the `DataSource` property of the `DataGridView` or similar control to the `DataTable`.

Here's a sample code :

```
using (var conn = new OracleConnection(connectionString))
using (var cmd = new OracleCommand("ProcedureName", conn) { 
                       CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure }) {
conn.Open();
using(OracleDataAdapter da = new OracleDataAdapter (cmd))
 {
   DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
   da.Fill(dataTable);
   dataGridView1.DataSource = dataTable;
 }
 conn.Close();
```

I personally never used Oracle, the code above is actually the general-ish code for such tasks. I hope this works.

Comment: If you are not getting any errors, then maybe you are not properly calling your stored procedure. Goto pastebin.com and paste your code there and comment the link. I will check the code.

Comment: Read my answer again

Comment: Read my answer again

Comment: sorry its still not displaying any data.
i think the problem is in my stored procedure
check out my stored procedure where it is wrong or right

Comment: Hm, could be your stored procedure. Show me.

Comment: create or replace procedure reportprocedure

is

cursor report is

select * from car;

rec report%rowtype;

begin

loop fetch report into rec;

exit when report%notfound;

dbms_output.put_line(rec.reg_no);

end loop;

end;

Comment: Execute your procedure from Oracle SQL Developer Tool. Download from [here](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/appdev/sql-developer.html).

Comment: its working from backend side but in front i dont know ho to execute it

Comment: Explain your situation. It seems like this is more than it's opposed.

Comment: i just want to use stored procedure which will select data from one table and display it on data grid view

Comment: Then what did you mean by front-end and back-end ? Are you talking about some web application here?

Comment: back end means my oracle where i create my stored procedure in which i use select statement
Front-end means my gui where I want to display data from stored procedure

Comment: I see. It is hard to tell from my end. Why don't you try a simple `Select` statements from code behind and see if that works.

Comment: it's a requirement

Comment: @Talha, just with a sample sql statement and see if things work correctly. If you still have issues, we can talk in chat.