# How to get all data from database into datagridview?

Tags: c#, database, oracle, datagridview

I want to display some data inside a `DataGridview` from Oracle server, but I only get the headers of the columns.

It's an old Oracle server (maybe 7 or 9). In SQL developer I see the data.

I tried this:

```
OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(oradb);
conn.Open();            
adpt = new OracleDataAdapter("select * from teszt;", conn);
dt = new DataTable();
adpt.Fill(dt);
dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Can you please remove `;` after query and try again? i.e. `"select * from teszt;"` --> `"select * from teszt"`

Comment: Removed it. But it still not works. :(

Comment: IMO you do not use the same account. It means in SQL Developer you execute the query under one credential, and your .NET connection is built using a credential with fewer privileges.

Comment: Please see the similar question- [Oracle database table in gridview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21253463/oracle-database-table-in-gridview)

Comment: There is something wrong with the connection string or query string.  Often people connect to a database and there is no data in the database.  So make sure your connection string is connecting to the correct server and the database on the server has a table teszt.  Does the table name have the letter 'z'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your code to this one..

```
public void BindGridView()
{
    try
    {
        using(OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection("add your connection details"))
        using(OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("select * from teszt", conn))
        {
            conn.Open();
            using(OracleDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
                dataTable.Load(reader);
                dataGridView1.DataSource = dataTable;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```