# Delete button for each row in a table asp.Net C#

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, row, tablerow

I have been wrestling with this for days now. I have created a page with records selected from a database table. I need to create a button delete for each row. The requirement is to use mysql with Asp.Net and C#. Below is the select code:

```
//Show Data Method
        public void ShowData()
        {
            using (connection)
            {
                using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
                {
                    command.CommandText = "SELECT CUST_ID,CUST_FNAME,CUST_SURNAME,CUST_DOB,CUST_GENDER,CUST_SMOKE_STATUS FROM customers";

                    connection.Open();

                    using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        var indexOfColumn1 = reader.GetOrdinal("CUST_ID");
                        var indexOfColumn2 = reader.GetOrdinal("CUST_FNAME");
                        var indexOfColumn3 = reader.GetOrdinal("CUST_SURNAME");
                        var indexOfColumn4 = reader.GetOrdinal("CUST_DOB");
                        var indexOfColumn5 = reader.GetOrdinal("CUST_GENDER");
                        var indexOfColumn6 = reader.GetOrdinal("CUST_SMOKE_STATUS");

                        htmlTable.Append("<table class='table table-bordered table-hover table-responsive'> ");
                        htmlTable.Append("<tr style='background-color:#c7c7c7; color: White;'><th>Customer ID.</th><th>First Name</th><th>Last Name</th><th>Date of Birth</th><th>Gender</th><th>Smoker Status</th><th>Actions</th></tr>");

                        while (reader.Read())
                        {

                            var value1 = reader.GetValue(indexOfColumn1);
                            var value2 = reader.GetValue(indexOfColumn2);
                            var value3 = reader.GetValue(indexOfColumn3);
                            var value4 = reader.GetValue(indexOfColumn4);
                            var value5 = reader.GetValue(indexOfColumn5);
                            var value6 = reader.GetValue(indexOfColumn6);

                            htmlTable.Append("<tr>");
                            htmlTable.Append("<td>" + value1.ToString() + "</td>");
                            htmlTable.Append("<td>" + value2.ToString() + "</td>");
                            htmlTable.Append("<td>" + value3.ToString() + "</td>");
                            htmlTable.Append("<td>" + value4.ToString() + "</td>");
                            htmlTable.Append("<td>" + value5.ToString() + "</td>");
                            htmlTable.Append("<td>" + value6.ToString() + "</td>");
                            htmlTable.Append("<td>" +
                            "<form id='form1' runat='server' action = 'customerprofile.aspx'><a href='customerprofile.aspx' class='btn btn-primary btn-xs' role='button'><span class='button-links'><i class='fa fa-folder-open'></i>  View</span></a> </form>" +
                            "</td>");


                            // now, do something what you want
                        }
                        htmlTable.Append("</tr>");
                        htmlTable.Append("</table>");
                        DBDataPlaceHolder.Controls.Add(new Literal { Text = htmlTable.ToString() });


                    }
                   // connection.Close();
                }
            }
        }
```

---

### BELOW IS THE DATABASE TABLE:

```
Customer_ID     First Name  Last Name    Age    Gender  Status   Action
4903015744088   George      litsa        18     Male    N        Delete
7208114443089   Kholie      Daliwe       19     Female  N        Delete
7903155743090   Tankiso     Ramokoena    20     Male    Y        Delete
7903015743091   Tiisetso    Masuku       21     Male    Y        Delete
7903105443092   Sindiswa    Phaswana     22     Female  N        Delete
7903113743093   Khanya      Gazi         23     Female  Y        Delete
```

Comment: Did you consider using a GridView?

Comment: @ConnorsFan Yes I have but due to MySql not allowing me to add GridView I have just decided to create tables with C#

Comment: Here is the way to use the GridView with MySQL: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16115985/how-to-populate-gridview-with-mysql.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things ...

Firstly, you're creating a `<form>` for every row, which is maybe not what you intend to do? Be that as it may, your form action and `<a href>` value are the same.

If you want to use a form, I'd suggest defining it around the table, and then using `'submit'` buttons to do the work. You could use `onclick` handlers to set a `<hidden>` value and then `submit();` the form. Your receiving page would need to retrieve the id of the row you're trying to delete, and process it from there.

Otherwise, leave out the form and just render the buttons as `<a>` links. I imagine that you'd want to render some query string paramters (e.g. `?id=x`) as part of the `href`.

Without knowing more about where your html is being rendered, that's about as much as I can suggest to look at.

Comment: Kindly assist with how I create the button using the code I have provided. I really appreciate the response.